# rails 3.1 fields_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, forms, ruby-on-rails-3.1, fields-for

Here is my `fields_for` block in my `edit` view of the `orders` controller

```
  <%= form_for @order do |f| %>

    <%= f.fields_for :order_fields do |builder| %>
      <%= builder.text_field :value %>
    <% end %>

  <% end %>
```

The problem I am having is that I would like to use an each loop to display information from the loop, but then i get the form displayed more than once. this is because i used the `accepts_nested_attributes_for :order_fields` statement.

Inside my `order_fields` table there is a column named `name` that I would like to display the information from in the form. How can I do this? The information from the `value` column in my database is displayed in my form already.

If i do

```
<%= f.fields_for :order_fields do |builder| %>
  <%= builder.text_field :name %>
  <%= builder.text_field :value %>
<% end %>
```

it displays information from both columns next to each other, but I would like the `:name` information not to be in a text box or anything. I would like it to be displayed as if i were to do something like:

```
<% @order.order_fields.each do |field| %>
  <%= field.name %>
<% end %>
```

I hope this make some sense :)
Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can access the object off of |builder| by calling .object on it

```
<%= f.fields_for :order_fields do |builder| %>
  <%= builder.object.name %>
  <%= builder.text_field :value %>
<% end %>
```